# React Context Does Not Propagate Changes to Other Consumers After Successful Provider Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-context

This is my first React Context implementation. I am using Gatsby and in my `layout.js` I added Context (with objects and handler function) that successfully gets passed to Consumer:

```
  import AppContext from "./AppContext"

  const Layout = ({ children }) => {

  let doAuthenticate = () => {
    authState = {
      isAuth: authState.isAuth === true ? false : true,
    }
  }

  let authState = { 
    isAuth: false,
    doAuthenticate: doAuthenticate
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AppContext.Provider value={authState}>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    </>
  )
```

I successfully execute function in Consumer:

```
<AppContext.Consumer>
   { value =>
      <button onClick={value.doAuthenticate}Sign in</button>
    }
</AppContext.Consumer>
```

I also see the value in `doAuthenticate` successfully gets updated.

However, another Consumer that is listening to Provider does not update the value. Why?

Comment: you are telling that another component is not getting the value, am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, another component does not get the value

Comment: You can simplify your `isAuth: authState.isAuth === true ? false : true,`
 by `isAuth: authState.isAuth !== true`

Comment: Noted simplification - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Gatsby, each instance of the Page will we wrapped with the Layout component and hence you will see that instead of creating one Context that is shared between pages, you end up creating multiple contexts.

Now multiple contexts cannot communicate with each other

The solution here is to make use of [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/?#wrapRootElement) api in `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` to wrap all your pages with a single layout component

```
import React from "react";
import Layout from "path/to/Layout";


const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {element}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export { wrapRootElement };
```

Comment: This sounds quite promising - thanks! However, after adding the above code to both `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` I do not see component with Consumer gets updated. Nothing is resolved. No errors. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Update: I did manage this to work using `useState` like this `let [authState, setAuthState] = useState({...initialAuthState});` based on https://medium.com/@chathuranga94/introduction-to-react-context-api-90f5e4d7a7a9. However, once I navigated to a different page, the update reverted back to default. I resolved it by localStorage to remember previous page value. The above solution does not seem to affect anything unless I am missing something.

Comment: Did you by any change use Layout in each individual page too

Comment: Each page such as index.js, about.js does have `<Layout>` in JSX.

Comment: @Vad That is exactly the problem, Since you already have Layout rendered as WrapRootElement, you wouldn't need to use Layout explicitly in JSX

Comment: You are correct. I tested and confirm the state persists across pages with the above solution. Thank you!